# Animar a posição de elementos div com MooTools

Tags: javascript, mootools

Como altero a posição de uma div após o carregamento da página? Ou seja, ter duas div's que apos o carregamento da pagina uma aparece da direita e a outra da esquerda, isto utilizando MooTools.

O exemplo mais parecido é [este](http://www.web2feel.com/freeby/scroll-effects/index2.html) (mas aqui com jQuery).

```css
<style type="text/css">
  .home_visit_extend1
  {
    margin-top: -20px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background:#00B9F2;
  }
  .home_visit_extend2
  {
    margin-top: 40px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background: url(homevisit_bg.jpg);
  }
  .home_visit_extend3
  {
    margin-top: 500px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background:none;

  } 

  .home_visit_menu
  {
    width:900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }  
  .home_visit_content
  {
    width:900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #hove_visit_content_left, #hove_visit_content_right {
    display: inline-block;    
    padding: 20px;   
  }  
  .home_visit_content_left_in
  {
    width:auto;
  }
  .hove_visit_content_right_in {
    width:450px;    
  }  

  .home_visit_icones{
    width:880px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .home_visit_icone_left{
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
    float: left;
    background:url(home_ico_circle_left.png) #FFFFFF;
    border-radius:89px; 
    border:6px solid #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;   
  }
  .home_visit_icone_middle{
    width:130px;
    height:130px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
    background:url(home_ico_circle_middle.png) #FFFFFF;
    border-radius:89px; 
    border:6px solid #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;   

  }
  .home_visit_icone_right{
    width:130px;
    height:130px;  
    float:right;
    background:url(home_ico_circle_right.png) #FFFFFF;
    border-radius:89px; 
    border:6px solid #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;   

  }

</style>
```

```html
 <div class="home_visit_extend1">
    <div class="home_visit_menu">
           <ul>
                  <li cLass="home_visit_menu_li">
                       Home
                  </li>
                  <li cLass="home_visit_menu_li">
                  </li>
                  <li cLass="home_visit_menu_li">
                  </li>
                  <li cLass="home_visit_menu_li">
                  </li>
           </ul>
        <a class="menu_core_mini core_mini_auth" href="/login/return_url/64-Lw%3D%3D">
            <?php echo $this->translate('Sign In') ?>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="home_visit_extend2">
    <div class="home_visit_content">
        <div id="hove_visit_content_left">
            <div id="hove_visit_content_left_in">
                <img src="homevisit_connection.png" border="0" style="margin-top:50px;" />
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div id="hove_visit_content_right">
        teste direito
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="home_visit_extend3">
    <div class="home_visit_icones">
        <div class="home_visit_icone_left">
        </div>
        <div class="home_visit_icone_middle">
        </div>
        <div class="home_visit_icone_right">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oi, Bruno, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Você chegou a tentar implementar [algum demo do Mootools](http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Fx.Slide)? O legal é você tentar primeiro e trazer aqui algum problema específico que tenha com o código. O guia [ask] tem mais detalhes.

Comment: Eu nem sei como começar.

Comment: O link para o manual que coloquei acima tem esta versão no JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/mootools/1.4/dependencies/more/

Comment: Ou seja, tens que ser capaz de montar um HTML que carregue os scripts necessários e que inclua os comandos de inicialização  do Moo. Se você não consegue montar um HTML, não tem sentido explicar como mudar a posição do div.

Comment: Então mostra seu código e explica sua dificuldade (é só [edit] a pergunta), é muito mais fácil oferecer ajuda vendo seu estágio atual de programação.

Comment: ta complicado publicar o codigo :/

Comment: sera que assim ja da? Obrigado

Comment: Fiz uma revisão. Para poder funcionar aqui como StackSnippet ou no JSFiddle, teria que tirar aquele `<?php ... ?>`. Parece que não tem necessidade nenhuma para a solução que você procura.

Comment: O JSFiddle (e semelhantes) são bem legais para maquetar blocos de código. Fiz uma simulação com seu código e como pode ver não funciona muito bem: http://jsfiddle.net/pw5ph87s/ . Enfim, MT não é minha especialidade, boa sorte!

Comment: @BrunoSerrano coloquei uma resposta no seguimento do link que tinha no inicio, quando colocou a pergunta. Vejo agora que mudou a pergunta. Vou editar a minha resposta mas quero perguntar antes: é esse o seu código ou vai mudar de novo para mais exato?

Comment: a pagina inicial ainda não esta pronta, portanto o codigo ainda o devo ter que alterar. Mas eu vou fazer testes com o exemplo que o caro amigo Sergio deixou em baixo depois deixo o feedback.

Comment: @Sergio, fui eu quem insistiu que ele mostrasse o próprio código em vez de mostrar um exemplo alheio feito em jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer isso com MooTools pode fazer assim:

```
var posts;
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    posts = $$('.post');
})

window.addEvent('scroll', function (e) {
    var altura = window.getScroll().y;
    posts.each(function (post) {
        if (post.getPosition().y > altura + 200) return;
        post.setStyle('opacity', 1).tween('left', '0px');

    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/coa9njjt/

Note também o CSS:

```
.post {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    left: -1000px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Quando a página carrega ponho em cache todos os posts. `// posts = $$('.post');`

Depois a cada chamada do evento *scroll* vou verificar a posição do scroll e comparar com a posição de cada post dentro do ciclo *each()*.

```
    var altura = window.getScroll().y;
    posts.each(function (post) {
        if (post.getPosition().y > altura + 200) return;
        // aqui o código para as divs que devem estar visíveis
        // e/ou vão ser animadas
    });
```

Se a condição se verificar então ponho a opacidade de volta e faço a animação com o tween.

```
post.setStyle('opacity', 1).tween('left', '0px');
```

Comment: Vou fazer testes com esse exemplo depois eu deixo o feedback. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @BrunoSerrano se explicares qual é a div no teu código que vem da esquerda e qual vem da direita posso mudar a resposta para ser mais exata.

Comment: A da esquerda é a home_visit_icone_left e a da drt é a home_visit_icone_right. Obrigado mesmo

Comment: @BrunoSerrano ok. E quer que mostrem com scroll como no link que deu?

Comment: @BrunoSerrano fica aqui um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/tw0cjq0n/

Comment: aqui ta o resultado final afuncionar sharingwm.com  Muito obrigado. Obrigado mesmo

Comment: @BrunoSerrano boa! Se quiseres podes mudar o tipo de efeito, tipo: `el.set('tween', {transition: 'bounce:out'});`, para fazer bounce como tinha o link que mandás-te. Eu estou mto envolvido no MooTools, se tiveres mais problemas pergunta aqui no SO pt ou en :) Já agora se a resposta ajudou podes marcar como aceite.

Comment: Ajudou e muito. Mais uma vez muito obrigado. ja esta como aceite.